# how to fix "files" must be an array when I run expo publish?

Tags: react-native, expo

after running command expo publish

```
Starting Metro Bundler.

Building iOS bundle

Building Android bundle

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 8264ms.

Building source maps

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 6624ms.

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 323ms.

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 203ms.

Building asset maps

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 6831ms.

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 6878ms.

Analyzing assets

Uploading assets

Uploading /app/assets/logo.png 

"files" must be an array.
```

I have already published my projects before but for some reason when I run command "expo publish" today it just keeps on stopping in uploading assets.

Comment: Me too. Just spent a few hours pulling my hair trying to figure out what's wrong with my PNG (nothing). It looks like an issue on Expo servers. Might be worth raising a ticket for Expo developers, I suspect they don't know about it yet https://github.com/expo/expo/issues

Comment: It appears to be fixed now! I just published successfully. Woohoo!

Comment: I just tried to publish again today 09/1/2020 (for date ref) and the error is now gone. I haven't done anything to make it work so I guess I can't answer my own question. For those who experienced the same problem and asking what I did to fix it, I just spend a few hours trying to figure it out, give up, sleep and now it's working. I just want to thank whoever fixed it.